# Tapping/Clicking on graph object activity not consistant - Facebook iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I recently implemented open graph in one of my iOS apps. Currently it posts a custom activity that when tapped is suppose to show more information about the activity.

This seems to be working for the majority of users. However, I've had a few report that when they click/tap on the posted activity it simply directs them to the app facebook page.

Has anyone else experienced this inconsistency? I cannot figure out what is going on.

Comment: Is there a pattern for which version of the Facebook iOS app the problem shows up in?

Comment: Good question C Abernathy. This was my first suspicion as well, but no. I have reports from users who are using the most up-to-date Facebook app who are experiencing this issue. I was testing using this version and everything seems to be working fine. Could it be caused by specific characters a user enters? For example, if they type a "#" and that then becomes part of the POST URL, could that interfere with the activity's action when tapped/clicked?

Comment: I don't think typing that character would pose a problem, but you could certainly try it out. Could you provide more info on the app or a sample problem URL, basically something else that can hopefully provide more clues?